# Connecting to ssh2 in localhost

Tags: php, cron, xampp, localhost

When I run following code in `localhost` in `Xampp` I saw an error that the connection was not success. Now I want know How Can I connect to `ssh2` in `localhost` in `Windows` in `Xampp` and what is `Username` and `Password` for this connection.' :

```
ssh2_connect('127.0.0.1','');
```

Comment: Do you have a server to connect to?

Comment: excuse me! I didn't understand. Do you mean real server or Localhost?

Comment: An SSH server. I'd guess you need one to connect to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For connect to ssh2 in localhost in Windows with Xampp:-

1) Download SSH2 PECL library from [PHP.net](https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2)

2) Extracted the archive's content:-

```
(2.1)copied/replaced libssh2.dll file to C:\Windows\system32

(2.2)placed php_ssh2.dll and php_ssh2.pdb files in the ext folder (e.g. C:\xampp\php\ext);
```

3)Remove ';' from the ;extension:php_ssh2.dll line in php.ini. If this line is not on your php.ini, add it.

4) restart the apache server.

Connecting code:-

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '/usr/local/bin/php -i');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. But a question what is username and password in localhost to connect ssh2 ? and if I use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as host is okay ? and what is the default` port` ?

Answer (score 0):

For you i have a perfect solution
Try installing wamp and then going in directory c:/wamp/ .. And then the folder for local host..
Turn try turning on the wamp service u installed above.
VIOLA!